# Why can't I change my eye color in New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I made a new character, because I dislike the eyes of my mayor character, and this one has "anime eyes" and I got a haircut, jumped a day, and it won't let me change it. I've had shampoodle in my town for months now. Do I need to have my CHARACTER around for a few weeks or something?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, say thanks by [accepting their answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and up-voting it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change your eye color after the following conditions are met:

1. Shampoodle has upgraded their equipment.
2. **You have changed your hairstyle and waited 2 weeks.** (This might be the one you're missing)
3. You must be in your own town
4. The gates to your town must be closed.

Additionally, the color of the contacts you receive will depend on how you answer Harriet's questions.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I've missed something or if this doesn't work for you.

***EDIT:***

I believe that since your character is new, you probably have to wait the 2 weeks after changing your new character's hairstyle before you can get the contacts.

Comment: Thank you. Everything I read had said "two weeks after opening", I guess they were ONLY going by the mayor character or something.

Answer (score 0):

According to animal crossing new leaf wikispaces,

> Once Shampoodle has been open for two weeks and you have changed your hairstyle at least once, she will upgrade her machine to change the color of your eyes with contacts (see: [Eye Guide](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/eye+guide)) and will begin offering the haircuts of the opposite gender.